# Duvida para pegar o nome de um campo input gerado automaticamente pelo php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um sistema legado em php que gera os input radios, sendo que os nomes destes campos sao dinamicos, como por exemplo o objeto $row.
E agora preciso pegar os valores dos campos radios e os seus respectivos nomes para que eles sejam salvos no banco atraves de uma requisicao ajax.
Veja o exemplo:

```
<?php
   $row = new stdClass();
   $row->sigla = array('ag', 'bg', 'cg');
   foreach ($row->sigla as $r) {
       echo "<tr>
                <td style='text-align:center'><input type='radio' value='1' name='$r' class='avaliacao'>SIM</td>
                <td style='text-align:center'><input type='radio' value='2' name='$r' class='avaliacao'>NAO</td>
                <td style='text-align:center'><input type='radio' value='3' name='$r' class='avaliacao'>N/A</td>
            </tr><br/>";
          }
        ?>
```

E o js que to tentando executar, mas sem saber como pegar o nome do campo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
           $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();//aqui retorna o valor correto
                //AQUI gostaria de pegar o valor do que foi clicado, mas como pegar o nome do campo?
            });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();//aqui retorna o valor correto
        var nome = $(this).attr("name");
    });
});
```

Comment: facil assim kkkkkk

Comment: Não deu certo ?

Comment: deu sim, muito facil, preciso estudar mais o js. Obrigado